# BlackBerry 10 WebWorks Native Packager Exception for PhoneGap application

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

When the building the application for BB 10 using webworks ,I am getting Native Pacakge Exception as specified in below pic

[image]

I am able to take build successfully in my system,but it is not happening some other system.Is some other system related changes to be done.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not even understand what your question is? Do you always get this error? Have you tried to package an example app? Did you check the versions of your IDE/tools?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used cordova cli through npm installation. That problem arises this way. I would recommend you to [follow this link](http://techbirds.in/?p=500) The second point in this explains how you have to do that.

Further the problem you are facing might be due to path problems. Do check you have all path variables set as mentioned in the [link](http://techbirds.in/?p=500). I felt this because of error: Protocol error.